# Recharts custom label

Tags: reactjs, charts, recharts

Custom label for React Recharts not working with Bar chart.

> http://jsfiddle.net/xpko4e7e/

```
 <Bar dataKey="pv"  fill="#8884d8"  label={<CustomLabel/>} />
```

Expected  to see the 'Label' text over of all bars.

**Update**

For example, if I have a chart in which multiple lines are there and each line is having some **label** but at the time of render some of the values are above another. How to overcome with this issue?

[Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOB3L.png)

Answer (score 22):

instead of returning a div try returning a text SVG element

```js
const CustomizedLabel = React.createClass({
  render () {
    const {x, y, stroke, value} = this.props;
  
    return <text x={x} y={y} dy={-4} fill={stroke} fontSize={10} textAnchor="middle">{value}</text>
  }
});
```

and then add

```js
<Bar dataKey="pv"  fill="#8884d8"  label={customLabel} />
```

like I have done here, http://jsfiddle.net/CharukaK/6u08o2oa/1/

Comment: To make it have more distance one can use `x={(entry.x - entry.cx) * 1.2 + entry.cx} y={(entry.y - entry.cy) * 1.2 + entry.cy}`

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is kind of old, but the issue is still there. We cannot use a HTML Element directly for a custom label. Only SVG Elements are working. But...

There is an element supported by SVG that is called [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

So something like this will work:

```js
const CustomLabel  = React.createClass({ 
  render() {  
        return (
          <g>
            <foreignObject x={0} y={0} width={100} height={100}>
              <div>Label</div>
            </foreignObject>
          </g>
        );
  }
});
```